# why void method cannot print inside of scriptlets and expression tags in jsp

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

When I try to print a method that return int using declaration tag usually scriplets and expression tags can print that method.

```
        <%! int print(int i, int j, int k) {
                return i + j + k;
        }%>

        <%= print(10, 20, 30)%> 
        <% out.print(print(10, 20, 300));%>
```

But when I try to print a void return method in using same tags I get a compilation error.

```
    <%! void print(int i, int j, int k) {
            System.out.print(i + j + k);
        }%>

    <%= print(10, 20, 30)%> 
    <% print(10, 20, 300);%>
```

..

```
C:\Users\dilin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Practice\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java:60: error: 'void' type not allowed here
  out.print( print(10, 20, 30));
                  ^1 error
```

Is this because void methods cannot give as a print output?

I'm new to web web development. So please bear with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is plain and simple. In your scriptlet, you are calling `java.io.PrintStream#print` method with no argument. Threrefore, the compiler gives you an error.

Refer to the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). While there are several overloaded variants of `print` method in `PrintStream`, none of them is a no-argument overload. Your custom `print` method returns `void` and hence you can't pass it to a method that accepts an argument.

**On a side note**, use of scriptlets is highly discouraged because they can make your application vulnerable to security threats.

Answer (score 0):

when you are writing out.print(), it expect some returned value. But your method is written as void. That is why it gives you error

Comment: And why void return an error? I mean scriplet and expression tags doesn't has any out.print() in second example.. So what is the issue in receiving end?